# Ruby on rails activerecord error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I am running in to a little error when I show all posts on the welcome page: `index.HTML.erb`. It works but my problem is that I get this snippet of code at the bottom of every post:

```
[#<Post id: 1, title: " Is The Death Of JavaScript Upon Us, Or Is A Univer...", 
image_url: "javascript.jpg", video_embed: "", category: "Article", 
content: "<p><strong>Editor&#8217;s note:</strong> <em>Péter ...", 
teasable_string: "", user_id: nil, created_at: "2013-06-19 14:09:13", 
updated_at: "2013-06-19 14:15:17", day: "19", month: "Jun 2013">]
```

I have looked for a solution but have found nothing yet. I have tried looking at ActiveRecord but I did not find anything.

Comment: It looks like you're accidentally printing an Array object. maybe you used `<%= %>` instead of `<% %>`

Comment: Just show us code in your `index.HTML.erb`

Comment: @yoavmatchulsky was right i had <%=  %> instead of <%  %> and it was giving me an array. thanks for the help.

Comment: In general - it's a good idea to include the actual code that's causing the problem. In this case, some people were able to *guess* what *might* have been causing the problem... but a other times it would be much more difficult for us to *guess*, and really, we shouldn't *have* to guess. if you want help, in future, please include the code that is causing the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're accidentlly printing an Array object.

Your code probably has something like this:

```
<%= @objects.each do |object| %>
```

instead of (without the `=` sign):

```
<% @objects.each do |object| %>
```

This will iterate the @objects array, but will also print out the return value of the `each` loop (which is the array itself).